# Container passed as template argument to class-template

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to create a simple template class wherein I create an object of the template class providing a container as the template type , from my understanding of templates , this should be no problem and should be handled exactly like int or char, but it always gives me an error saying:

```
"template argument 1 is invalid"
```

Here is the line at which I encounter this error :

```
templateTest<(std::list<int>)> testingTheTemplate;
```

Here is a  skeleton of the template class

```
template <class testType> class templateTest 
{
   /* use some iterators and print test data here */
};
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: That would just create a template with "int" as the template type, that's not what I am trying to do.

Comment: didnt your forget to place ; (colon) after class definition? I mean at the end of your second code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the semicolon after the class definition:

```
template <class testType> class templateTest 
{

}; // <- semicolon
```

Also, declare your instantiation as this:

```
templateTest<std::list<int> > testingTheTemplate;
                       // ^^^ required space (C++03)
```

No parenthesis and notice the space in between.

Before C++11, `<<` and `>>` are treated as operators. You must separate them in cases like this.

Comment: Ok , this is new , I was under the impression that whitespaces never make any difference in C++ (unless used inside tokens which cause stuff to foobar)
Thanks for the help !

Comment: They do in this case. >> and << are treated as bit shifts. (except for C++11 I think).

Comment: Nitpick: This is not a specialization, but an instantiation.

Comment: @BjörnPollex from the perspective of specifying a type for the template, it is a specialization , but an instance of that specialized class is created right ? Do we still refer to the scenario as specialization ?

Comment: That was my reasoning as well... but isn't a specialization a different declaration with implementation that behaves in a specific way?

Comment: A specialization is when you provide a special implementation for a template for a given type. See [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.7).

Answer (score 1):

It should be
`templateTest<std::list<int> > testingTheTemplate;` in C++03
or `templateTest<std::list<int>> testingTheTemplate;` in C++11

Comment: templateTest<std::list<int>> 

doesn't work , that's what I gave initially , but it seems that the get from '>>' operator has higher precedence.

Comment: @angryInsomniac: that's why he gave both the old c++03 version (that suffers from that problem) and the new C++11 version (that doesn't but isn't supported by every compiler or needs special compiler flags)

Comment: @angryInsomniac your compiler doesn't support current C++ standard (C++11)

Comment: It does work on newer compilers that follow the C++11 standard. Perhaps your compiler can take a -c++0x or -c++11 option?

Comment: @Abyx I'm not sure , am using a MAC at work for some of my learning activities , OSX and X-code arent really my thing, I'll check on my windows machine at home and see it it works.

Comment: @angryInsomniac check ISO/IEC 14882-2011.